# Navigation Bar does not work when opened with swipe to right but does when the menu button is pressed

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

The navigation bar open when swiped but menu items are unresponsive the nav header part updates as it should but if nav button is pressed the menu item button work properly in some devices it does not allow swiping to open the drawer

on swiping allowed devices it shows the option as selected but does not trigger it such problems are not occurring in the android studio emulator,i want the functions to work reguardless of opening way is swipe or drawer press if u want to try the app apk can be installed from here https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnbGL2sgNSjugQiS3ELexUrBfHQ8?e=XOanwt

Thank you in advance for takeing time to help

entire java activity code is as follows

```
package com.example.testing;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.net.URI;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Navigation
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    //CardView
    CardView cdmarks,cdattendance,cdlibrary,cdidcard,cdrailwayconcession,cdquestion,cdcalendar;
FirebaseUser currentuser;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    String userID,baronmail;


    private static int splash=3000;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        baronmail="baroncandy09@gmail.com";
        currentuser=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        userID=currentuser.getUid();
        //Navigation Page
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        /*toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);*/
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentuser=mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(Main2Activity.this, drawerLayout,0, 0);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        updatenavhead();


        //CardView FindViewByID
        cdmarks = findViewById(R.id.marks);
        cdattendance = findViewById(R.id.attend);
        cdidcard = findViewById(R.id.idcard);
        cdrailwayconcession = findViewById(R.id.railwayconcession);
        cdlibrary = findViewById(R.id.library);
        cdquestion = findViewById(R.id.question);
        cdcalendar = findViewById(R.id.calendar);

        //CardView marks
        cdmarks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,MarksActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        //CardView attendance
        cdattendance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,AttendanceActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        //CardView idcard
        cdidcard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,IDActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        //CardView railway concession
        cdrailwayconcession.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(Main2Activity.this,RailwayConActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        //CardView library
        cdlibrary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,Library.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        //CardView Question
        cdquestion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,QuestionActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        //CardView Calendar
        cdcalendar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,Calendaractivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        //Navigation Item selected event

    }//outside saved instance like taught press and slide work

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem){
        if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem)){
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuitem) {
                    switch (menuitem.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.Setting:
                            /*setting();*/
                            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Display "+menuitem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent1 = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, com.example.testing.Setting.class);
                            startActivity(intent1);

                            break;

                        case R.id.Share:
                            Intent share= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            share.setType("text/plain");
                            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"install clgprg:\n  "+"https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnbGL2sgNSjugQiS3ELexUrBfHQ8?e=XOanwt");
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"share link via"));
                            break;

                        case R.id.makers:
                            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Display "+menuitem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent4 = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, com.example.testing.madeby.class);
                            startActivity(intent4);
                            break;

                        case R.id.Feedback:
                            Intent intent2 =new Intent( Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,baronmail);
                            intent2.setType("message/rfc822");
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent2,"chose mail"));
                            break;

                        case R.id.logout:
                            //makes so have to log in again
                            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= getSharedPreferences(Login.pref_name,0);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPreferences.edit();
                            editor.putBoolean("hasloggedin",false);
                            editor.commit();
                            //logs out from firebase side
                            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                            Intent intent5= new Intent(Main2Activity.this,com.example.testing.Login.class);
                            startActivity(intent5);
                            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Logged out..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                    }


                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);

    }
    
    //Navigation Function:-outside the main return idk but works
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
}
public void updatenavhead()
{
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    View headview=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    TextView navusername=headview.findViewById(R.id.usernameplace);
    ImageView navpfp=headview.findViewById(R.id.pfpback);

    Glide.with(this).load(currentuser.getPhotoUrl()).into(navpfp);
    reference.child(userID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot)
        {
            RegisterUser reguser=snapshot.getValue(RegisterUser.class);

            if (reguser!=null)
            {
                String FNAME= reguser.fname;

                navusername.setText("Hello "+FNAME);

                Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(reguser.getpfp()).centerCrop().into(navpfp);


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: the nav drawer has a header which updates depending on users profile pic on login but looks like its not completely related and I added it in by mistake am removing it